# Getting error property of undefined error in Angular

Tags: angular

I have declared an object and assining value to it. I am getting error Id of Undefined in angular 7 application. The object LegacyStrategyTypeSelectedItem is undefined

```
 public LegacyStrategyTypeSelectedItem: {Id: number, Name: string };
```

Assigning value

```
this.LegacyStrategyTypeSelectedItem.Id = this.ClassificationOverrideDetails.ClassificationEntities.find(x=> x.ID == selectedClassficationId).LegacyStrategyId;
```

Answer (score 0):

you defined the object but it doesn't have value

so you need to assign a value to `this.LegacyStrategyTypeSelectedItem` before using it

for example

```
public LegacyStrategyTypeSelectedItem: {Id: number, Name: string } = { Id : null , Name: null}
```

or

```
this.LegacyStrategyTypeSelectedItem = { 
    Id: this.ClassificationOverrideDetails.ClassificationEntities.find(x=> x.ID == selectedClassficationId).LegacyStrategyId , 
    Name: null 
};
```